# Valor de um dos campos do array

Tags: php, array

Estou precisando verificar qual o valor de um dos campos de um *array* mas não estou conseguindo.

```
var_dump($array_exemplo);

array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(3) {
     ["primeiro"]=>
        string(1) "1"
     ["segundo"]=>
        string(1) "2"
     ["terceiro"]=>
        string(1) "3"
   }
}

var_dump($array_exemplo["segundo"]);
```

> Notice: Undefined index: segundo in ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem um *array* dentro de outro então não pode fazer de conta que não tem esse *array* intermediário.

```
$array_exemplo = array(
    0 => array(
        "primeiro" => "1",
        "segundo" => "2",
        "terceiro" => "3"
    )
);
var_dump($array_exemplo);
var_dump($array_exemplo[0]);
var_dump($array_exemplo[0]["segundo"]);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/14ewDh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ltpcptje-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/MultiDimentional.php).

Comment: Perfeito... era isso mesmo.